# Duplicates while inserting a result set into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In my application I have a report called 'Daily Exception Report' used to display exceptions of ISA. In this table I see duplicate entries(exactly two identical rows in the report).

Technical details.

The exceptions report will be displayed with the data available in a `table` called `ExceptionFirstReported` which has duplicate entries.
The `Insert Statement` used to `insert` the row into the `ExceptionFirstReported` is in the `stored procedure` `usp_Refresh_Daily_Exception_Report`.

```
INSERT INTO ExceptionFirstReported(
       InvestorReference, ExceptionReason, First_Reported_Date, RelativeRef)
  SELECT InvestorReference, ExceptionReason, Dateupdated, RelatedInvRef FROM (
      SELECT * FROM DailyExceptionReport As DER
               WHERE NOT EXISTS
                 (SELECT ExcepRptd.InvestorReference
                  FROM ExceptionFirstReported AS ExcepRptd
                  WHERE DER.InvestorReference = ExcepRptd.InvestorReference
                  AND DER.ExceptionReason = ExcepRptd.ExceptionReason
                  AND DER.RelatedInvRef = ExcepRptd.RelativeRef))
  AS CI
  JOIN currentISAs AN CI.InvestorReference = Status_Inv_Ref
```

We think there can be no duplicate entries with this statement at two different instances, as there will be no row that has identical `InvestorReference`, `ExceptionReason` and `RelatedInvRef.

However we are having duplicate enteries. This is the only `insert` statement used to insert rows into the `table`.
And the tables `DailyExceptionReport` and `currentISAs` didn't contain duplicates before.

The above stated insert query has been called in a store procedure 'usp_refresh_dailyreport'  and the SP has been executed only once in a cycle.

@returnvalue = Exec usp_refresh_dailyreport

if @ returnvalue = 1

then

InvestorReference   ExceptionReason    First_reported_dt
Recent_reported_dt           relativeref         report_gen_date

442643169642           Nil Balance      2012-04-11 09:54:00
2012-05-04 23:58:00                                            NULL

442643169642           > One ISA        2012-04-21 06:30:00                               2012-04-23 23:58:00           452750423823           NULL

442643169642           > One ISA        2012-04-21 06:30:00
2012-04-23 23:58:00           452750423823          NULL

Guys in the above data of the ' ExceptionFirstReported' table the last two rows are identical, and contain the same relativeref (not null). Apologise guys the 'relativeref' is not null field but I might hold blank data as like the first row.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this insert concurrently in multiple threads? Two threads can both run the exists check, find nothing, and do the insert for the same data.

I recommend that you add a unique index to make 100% sure that you aren't inserting duplicate records. Better have an (actionable) exception than corrupt data.

You can fix this by making our statement run under the transaction isolation level serializable.

Comment: thnk buddy.The issue is I can't add index to the table because with primary index added to the table, if the insert query tries to insert the duplicate, the process will stop wit an error. I am working wit bank live system. This report has to be generated daily.